# How can I mirror all traffic to another server?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have 2 different CentOS servers (A and B) on different networks. How can I mirror/retranslate all traffic from all ports from server A to server B?

Server A has many runned applications that sometimes changes listening port to another random available port. Any clients in internet can access to these applications through server A, and they shouldn't know the real IP of server B. How can I configure server A for this?

For example:

- IP of server A is `30.40.50.60`
- IP of server B is `21.42.53.64`

P.S. The apps themselves don't reveal information about the network. I'm only interested in a method of relaying traffic to a specific server

Answer (score 0):

A port mirror in a switch would be the most common. Are these physical or virtual hosts? Self-hosted or cloud-based?

Comment: Self-hosted physical hosts located on 2 different cities. Unfortunately, the task must be solved at the server level. No changes in switch

Answer (score 0):

Would I be correct in thinking your application relates to the likes of DDoS evasion?

If your application is HTTP, then it sounds like what you might be after is the concept of a reverse proxy; httpd and nginx are commonly used in this regard, although there are many options these days (particularly if you're into cloud-native). There are also cloud service vendors such as CloudFlare that specialise in this.

You can do something similar with plain TCP too. Haproxy would be one-such example, and at least knowing what the PROXY protocol is can be helpful if you want to maintain visibility of the client IP and have programmer-level control over the service.

If UDP, you can do this with tools such as port mirroring.

If you want to be able to replay (and rewrite) traffic after the fact, then tools such as tcprewrite and tcpreplay (they work with UDP too), or tools like Scapy (a Python framework) can be useful, depending on your use-case.

Is the fact that you have dynamic ports a problem for you, or is that a concious decision, as I could imagine both scenarios.

Comment: No, this is not for DDoS evasion.Just need to proxy all requests through another server so that no one could to know the real IP of the main server